# integrate an home page on youtube

Tags: iframe, youtube, html

I'm trying to find out how to integrate a personal home page on YouTube like this iframe example:

http://www.youtube.com/user/AudiofAmerica/home
(source: audiusafb.com/youtube2012/ cms wordpress)

maybe this issue ? 
http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=30085&guide=30071&page=guide.cs&answer=1727240

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)